Revert element's style change in its ::after pseudo-element
(background:) while looking for a way to display a timestamp in a human readable format, but copy the full timestamp when the user selects and copy, without complex tricks or any JavaScript, I found this simple CSS-based trick:


div { font-size: 10px; color: purple; }
div.alt { color: navy; }

.timestamp[data-relative-timestamp] {
    font-size: 0.1px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}
.timestamp[data-relative-timestamp]::after {
    content: attr(data-relative-timestamp);
    font-size: initial;
    color: initial;
}
<div>
  Timestamp with human readable alt:
  <span class="timestamp" data-relative-timestamp="1 minute ago">2024-10-23 10:22</span>
</div>
<div class="alt">
  Timestamp with human readable alt in alternate-style div:
  <span class="timestamp" data-relative-timestamp="1 minute ago">2024-10-23 10:22</span>
</div>
<div>
  Timestamp without human readable alt:
  <span class="timestamp">2024-10-23 10:36</span>
</div>

<div>
  <br/><br/>Test paste here:<br/>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>



it manipulates font-size and color of the element to hide it visually, but let the user select and copy it;
however I can't find a way to restore the CSS style of the ::after element, as initial resets any style change, not only that introduced by .timestamp[data-relative-timestamp]; inherit revert and unset do not work ( element stays "invisible"); ideal should be to inherit from parent's parent, not from parent.
note that the .timestamp element could be inserted into any parent element (here demonstrated with div and div.alt parents, which have different style), so copying the CSS style into .timestamp::after is not  a viable solution.

"ideal should be to inherit from parent's parent, not from parent" - that kind of "generation skipping" isn't a thing in CSS inheritance. The only way I see to solve this, would be to not only define the font-size on whatever the relevant parent/ancestor is, but also set it as a CSS variable at that same location. Then your pseudo element could "access" the content of that variable.

however using font-size: 1% to hide text is not reliable, as in some places it doesn't actually go "invisible" (is some ancestor somehow preventing a too small font size?)

My browser doesn't let me select either of the "1 minute ago" texts in your above snippet, btw. Only the version without the human readable alt lets me do that.

Plus, it would simply confuse the eff out of me, if what I find in my clipboard afterwards, doesn't resemble the actual text I visually selected in the first place. And what if the user marked only part of your "human readable" text - say, I only want to copy&paste the "minute ago" part (because I wanted to get it translated for example) - what result should I expect in my clipboard then (if the above was working as intended) ...? Do your users a favor - and implement an explicit little button or something, that puts the desired value into their clipboard via JS.

Playing with relative (percent) font size allows to undo the change in parent element by inverting the percentual change (inverse of 1% is 10000%), however it is not applicable for the color:


div { font-size: 10px; color: purple; }
div.alt { color: navy; }

.timestamp[data-relative-timestamp] {
  font-size: 1%;
  /* color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01); */
}
.timestamp[data-relative-timestamp]::after {
  content: attr(data-relative-timestamp);
  font-size: 10000%;
  /* color: revert; */
}
<div>
  Timestamp with human readable alt:
  <span class="timestamp" data-relative-timestamp="1 minute ago">2024-10-23 10:22</span>
</div>
<div class="alt">
  Timestamp with human readable alt in alternate-style div:
  <span class="timestamp" data-relative-timestamp="1 minute ago">2024-10-23 10:22</span>
</div>
<div>
  Timestamp without human readable alt:
  <span class="timestamp">2024-10-23 10:36</span>
</div>

<div>
  <br/><br/>Test paste here:<br/>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>



but I found that sometimes setting font-size: 1% to hide text doesn't work (renders the same as ~50%)... is some ancestor somehow preventing a too small font size?

Some browsers apply a minimum font size for accessibility purposes. Generally 0 means  0, but 1px will be rendered at the user's preferred minimum size.

There are some ideas going around on inheriting values from a grandparent or other ancestor, but nothing close to implementation in browsers yet. One idea is inheriting from a named ancestor, another is scope isolation, where the values wouldn't escape via inheritance from a defined scope.
